# vscode dev container - attach to existing container when opening vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I am using a dev container to develop my c++ project on a microcontroller. The have my entire toolchain in a docker-compose / dockerfile, which autorestarts.

I have to follow these steps every time:

- open vscode
- open palette
- dev containers: attach to running container
- select my dev container

A second vscode will open, which connects to the docker container.

I always start vscode from a terminal:

- cd to repo
- `code .`

Is there a way to make vscode remember that I always want to connect to my dev container when vscode is openened in that specific repo?

I am reading stuff on `devcontainer.json`, but I can't figure out how to define it so that i just opens an already existing container.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use devcontainer CLI to open the devcontainer directly. I found the solution here: [bh231's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72129098/3806733)

You can install it directly in VS Code and then you need to add the devcontainer CLI path to your $PATH variable. After terminal restart you can go to your repo folder (as you did before) but then you need to call `devcontainer open` which will open your devcontainer directly from there.